# c# Ответ на запрос

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, binary

Привет в ответ за запрос хочу вернуть звуковой файл.
В гуголе нашел StreamReader(Writer), BinaryReader(Writer) но все примеры рассматриваются на текстовых файлах можно или записать  в массив байтов звуковой файл и его вернуть

Comment: Можно. Но детали очень сильно зависят от формата же

Comment: ну тот же банальный mp3

Comment: любой файл это массив байт, поэтому можете спокойно читать и записывать как массив байт любой файл независимо от его типа. Другой вопрос, если вам нужно менять его содержимое, для этого уже обязательно нужно знать формат внутренней структуры файла.